# Customize iPhone view for iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, interface-builder

I have converted a very simple iPhone app to Universal app. Now I need to customize the view on the iPad to use a higher resolution image for the background, move and resize some labels, etc.

How can I do it without changing the iPhone version? I can see that there is a new MainWindow-iPad.xib, but when I open in IB, it looks empty.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did Xcode create other iPad specific nib files for you? If you are adding your view(s) to the mainWindow at application launch it will be those that need modifying.

If you are adding images programatically, you can use different resources per target. When you drag a resource into your Xcode project (say background.png) you can select which target to apply the resource to. So if you have an iPadResources folder, you can put your larger background.png into it and add it only to the iPad version. (Remember to GetInfo on the old resource, go to Targets and untick the iPad target).

Hope this helps

Comment: Xcode created a new iPad specific .xib file, but then I need to put all UI objects again in this new view and set sizes for iPad?